# How to solve ODE $\frac{\partial }{\partial t} f(x,t)= i x^2 f(x,t), f(x,0)= g(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this ODE in $t,$ with parameter $x:$

$\frac{\partial }{\partial t} f(x,t)= i x^2 f(x,t), f(x,0)= g(x), x,t \in \mathbb R.$

Comment: Try transforms like fourier or laplace, i think they should work fine. Though, i don't remember much.

Comment: $A e^{ix^2 t} $ is a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that $x$ is not function of $t$, this is a separable ODE

$$ \frac{\frac{\partial }{\partial t} f(x,t) }{f(x,t)}dt=i x^2 dt$$

$$\ln|f(x,t)|=i x^2 t+\text{constant}$$
With the condition $f(x,0)=g(x)$ :
$$f(x,t)=g(x)e^{ix^2 t}$$